# Subtract all values from one value and MULTIPLY. Move to next value and repeat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with three columns 'a','b' and 'c'

```
[a]  [b]   [c]
 2    2    12 
 11  5.95  12 
 10  16.7  12
```

What I need is an extra column 'd', which represents following calculation:

((2-11) * 5.95 + (2-10) * 16.7) /12 = -15.59583333

((11-2) * 2 + (11-10) * 16.7) /12 = 2.8916666667

((10-11) * 5.95 + (10-2) * 2) /12 = 0.8375

```
[a]  [b]   [c]    [d]
 2    2    12  -15.59583333
 11  5.95  12   2.8916666667
 10  16.7  12   0.8375
```

It should be highly dynamic, so the row count can differ. Speed is also a concern thats why I want to avoid for loops.

I tried to use .apply() and .pivot() to get it in an easy format to just call sub() and mul(), but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `apply` through series `a` and do the calculation for each element separately:

```
df['d'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: ((x - df.a) * df.b / df.c).sum())
df
```

[image]

---

Or you can pre calculate `df.b / df.c` to make this slightly more efficient:

```
coef = df.b / df.c
df['d'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: ((x - df.a) * coef).sum())
```

Comment: the initial input provided by me, is behind a groupby object. So when I run your code with apply on the group object it returns NAN for the 'd'.
I tried with .transform but this gives me only '0'

Comment: Then probably `.groupby(...).apply(lambda g: g.assign(d = g.a.apply(lambda x: ((x - g.a) * g.b / g.c).sum())`. Without knowing your actual data, I can't guarantee that solves your problem.

Comment: You are a f**** genius! Thanks a lot dude